# broadcast receiver in android

Tags: android

I m receiving broadcast in adnroid

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  }
}
```

in onReceive method I want the ID or number of particular device which receive my message..
so how can I get particular device number??
pleas help me

Answer (score 0):

[Retrieving Device Information on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201112/retrieving-device-information-on-android)

May be this is what you need. Take a look.

And take a look at this app's source code also :-

[Qsysinfo Source Code.](http://code.google.com/p/qsysinfo/source/browse/)