# How to get processor speed and RAM in android device

Tags: android

Could anyone help me how to get processor name, speed and RAM of Android device via code.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875415/how-to-detect-android-cpu-speed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201112/retrieving-device-information-on-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its only possible on a rooted device or your app is running as system application.

For wanted informations you have to look in the running kernel, as i know this informations
cant be obtained by the android system itself.

To obtain informations about the CPU, you can read and parse this file:
/proc/cpuinfo

To obtain memory informations, you can read and parse this file:
/proc/memory

Answer (score 21):

You can get processor, RAM and other hardware related information as we normally get in Linux.
From terminal we can issue these command in a normal Linux system. You **don't** need to have a **rooted device** for this.

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Similarly you can issue these commands in android code and get the result.

```
public void getCpuInfo() {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/cpuinfo");
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcmd);
        tv.setText(getStringFromInputStream(is));
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "------ getCpuInfo " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void getMemoryInfo() {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/meminfo");
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcmd);
        tv.setText(getStringFromInputStream(is));
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "------ getMemoryInfo " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = null;

    try {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "------ getStringFromInputStream " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        if(br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "------ getStringFromInputStream " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }       

    return sb.toString();
}
```