# Android CPU detection & Tegra

Tags: android, cpu, tegra

In Android (non-rooted), is there any API or way to detect at runtime an Android CPU, and specially TEGRA devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On any Android device, CPU information can can be gleaned by reading `/proc/cpuinfo` programmatically as shown [**here**](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-get-cpu-information-on-android/) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19557326/319204).

Parse the value of the `hardware` tag listed in `/proc/cpuinfo` to determine the device. The value is usually the codename of the Android device. With a given "codename" value of the `hardware` tag, lists like **[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_devices_supported_by_CyanogenMod)** will help you determine the Android device.